# Changing the value of buttons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Whenever I click on a certain letter, I want the first slot `value` from the beginning to be changed to the letter `value` I clicked on. Is it correct that I put the `letter.onclick = letterClick(this);` into the `for` loop or should I realise it some other way. Also, what should the `letterClick()` function contain?

```
// Makes slots and letters for the chosen word.
function maker() {
    for (i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
        var slot = document.createElement("input");
        var letter = document.createElement("input");
        var letters=(shuffledWord).split("");
        slot.type = "submit";
        slot.value = "";
        slot.id = "slot" + i;
        slot.setAttribute('id', 'slot');
        letter.type = "submit";
        letter.value = letters[i];
        letter.id = "letter" + i;
        letter.onclick = letterClick(this);
        letter.setAttribute('id', 'letter');
        document.getElementById("slotbar").appendChild(slot);
        document.getElementById("letterbar").appendChild(letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating more buttons will mean there's a greater supply with an equal demand, so the value of buttons will decrease. But if you have very few buttons then those buttons that are left will be worth a lot. If you have direct control over the supply of buttons then you can change the value that way. If not then maybe you can persuade people that buttons are awesome, thus driving up demand & price. Or try to convince them buttons suck and they shouldn't want any, thus lowering demand & price. Outside of this I'm not sure.

Comment: LOL, sounds like my economy class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, `this` refers to the context where you run the method `maker`. So mostly you get this as window, and you do not want to invoke the function when you bind the handler for onClick. It should be a function reference.

Try

```
 letter.onclick = letterClick.bind(this, letter);
```

Now the function will be invoked with your first argument as that letter element.

When you do

```
letter.onclick = letterClick(this);
```

it immediately invokes the function and set its result as handler, i.e if it doen't return another function ref that is the real handler, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you! This actually works, as it gives me the letter value in the function letterClick(), but how should I replace the slot value with the value of the letter?

Comment: @danrodi Do you mean inside the function letterClick?

Comment: You can do elem.previousElementSibling.value = 'value of letter'